# Jasmine toThrowError of proctractor error

Tags: jasmine

Is it possible to catch a protractor error? I tried with:

```
let MagicBtn = element(by.css('.submitBtn'));
expect(() => {(MagicBtn.click();}).toThrowError("Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, a[id=link33])");
```

or different cases like:

```
expect(MagicBtn.click()).toThrowError("Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, a[id=link33])");
```

or create a new function and catch it via throwerror:

```
var foo = function() {
                MagicBtn.click();
            };
let exception1 = new TypeError('Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, a[id=link33])')

expect(foo).toThrowError(exception1);
```

but the toThrowError catches the errors not caused by protractor (which is understandable of course) - I just think if it is workaroundable

Comment: Why would you want to catch the error? If you want to check that element is not there, then use `expect(MagicBtn.isPresent()).toBe(false)`.

Comment: To use it in the if condition - I can't use the expect as long as it is a promise

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `isPresent()` will return you a promise. `expect` can handle/resolve promises for you so the above would work no?

Comment: I cannot use if(expect(by.css('.foo'))==true) { //code }, I get error that I can't use promise to the conditional

Comment: Apologies, I don't really understand your use case here. What is it you want to do if an assertion fails? If it fails, the test will fail and you will be notified that your test has failed right? What action do you want to perform when your test has failed and why?

Comment: Apologies for long delay :( In my test there might be exception, that when I open the page, the button is not available. I would like to create the `if` condition for exception that the button is not possible (that the code will go back and go for the next step). I don't know if it's possible in jasmine - this is the question :) or maybe you'll know how can I do it in other way, this `if` when the button is not available?